# JsonConverter equivalent in using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I'm starting to migrate some code I have from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` in a .net Core 3.0 app.

I migrated the properties from

`[JsonProperty("id")]` to `[JsonPropertyName("id")]`

but I have some properties decorated with the `JsonConverter` attribute as:

`[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
 [JsonPropertyName("birth_date")]
 DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }`

But I cannot find the equivalent of this Newtonsoft converter in `System.Text.Json` Does someone know how can this be achieved in .net Core 3.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use Newtonsoft instead rather than migrating it all over?

Comment: That's another question, but I'd like to know if this can be achieved in `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Not sure the new JSON objects are mature enough to cope with all circumstances right now, but happy to be proven wrong. Making .NET Core 3 use Newtonsoft though, is a one line change I believe.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`System.Text.Json` now supports custom type converters in .NET 3.0 preview-7 and above.

You can add converters that match on type, and use the [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.0) attribute to use a specific converter for a property.

Here's an example to convert between `long` and `string` (because javascript doesn't support 64-bit integers).

```cs
public class LongToStringConverter : JsonConverter<long>
{
    public override long Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            // try to parse number directly from bytes
            ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = reader.HasValueSequence ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray() : reader.ValueSpan;
            if (Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out long number, out int bytesConsumed) && span.Length == bytesConsumed)
                return number;

            // try to parse from a string if the above failed, this covers cases with other escaped/UTF characters
            if (Int64.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out number))
                return number;
        }

        // fallback to default handling
        return reader.GetInt64();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, long value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then apply to your property as follows:

```
// Be sure not to use Newtonsoft.Json which also has a JsonConverter attribute
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(LongToStringConverter))]
    public long MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Or register the converter by adding it to the `Converters` list in `JsonSerializerOptions`

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new LongToStringConverter());
});
```

*Note: in .NET 5 and later, to make your converter [handle null values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?view=dotnet-6-0&pivots=dotnet-6-0#handle-null-values) override [`HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull?view=net-5.0) and return `true`.  In .NET Core 3 this [was not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286291/3744182).*

Comment: Just for reference: If someone is searching for `StringEnumConverter` in System.Text.Json:

`using System.Text.Json.Serialization; [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.0.

Comment: How do I convert to a custom type? `{x: {foo:1,bar:2,baz:{apple:1,orange:2, juice:[1,2,3,4,5]}}`

Comment: @boop You create your type then write a converter that inherits from `JsonConverter<YourType>` with the read and write logic you need. The documentation has lots of samples that show you how to interact with the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to

Comment: @FranzHuber23 It does serialize, but it does not respect the `EnumMember` attribute value and thus the Enum name is serialized instead [System.Text.Json: JsonStringEnumConverter ignores its JsonNamingPolicy during deserialization. #31619](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31619)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the `JsonConverterAttribute` in the namespace `System.Text.Json.Serialization`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.0