# System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

Using the **System.Text.Json** serializer capabilities in .NET Core, how can I specify a custom value for an enum value, similar to `JsonPropertyName`? For example:

```
public enum Example {
  Trick, 
  Treat, 
  [JsonPropertyName("Trick-Or-Treat")] // Error: Attribute 'JsonPropertyName' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.
   TrickOrTreat
}
```

Comment: Not supported via attributes in [tag:.net-core-3.0], see [Support for EnumMemberAttribute in JsonConverterEnum #41578](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41578).

Comment: Probably with a [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: Do you need to use `System.Text.Json`? Or would it suit you to switch to Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**This is not currently supported out of the box in [.net-core-3.0](/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.0), [.net-5](/questions/tagged/.net-5), [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0), [.net-7.0](/questions/tagged/.net-7.0) or [.net-8.0](/questions/tagged/.net-8.0)**.

Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, have elected to close [the relevant issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29975#issuecomment-1235455864) requesting this functionality, essentially because they can't be bothered to implement it. Thus you will need to create your own [`JsonConverterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterfactory) that serializes enums with custom value names specified by attributes, or use a NuGet package that does the same such as [Macross.Json.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions).

**If you are working in .NET 7 or later, or only need to serialize but not deserialize enums with custom names in earlier versions**, custom names can be easily supported by creating a `JsonConverterFactory` that adapts [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter) by constructing a customized [`JsonNamingPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy) for each `enum` with [`[EnumMember(Value = "xxx")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute) applied to any enum value.

I chose `EnumMemberAttribute` because this is the attribute supported by Newtonsoft, but you could use `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` instead if you prefer.

First, introduce the following converter:

```
public class JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    private readonly JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy;
    private readonly bool allowIntegerValues;
    private readonly JsonStringEnumConverter baseConverter;

    public JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter() : this(null, true) { }

    public JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = null, bool allowIntegerValues = true)
    {
        this.namingPolicy = namingPolicy;
        this.allowIntegerValues = allowIntegerValues;
        this.baseConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter(namingPolicy, allowIntegerValues);
    }
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => baseConverter.CanConvert(typeToConvert);

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var query = from field in typeToConvert.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                    let attr = field.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>()
                    where attr != null && attr.Value != null
                    select (field.Name, attr.Value);
        var dictionary = query.ToDictionary(p => p.Item1, p => p.Item2);
        if (dictionary.Count > 0)
            return new JsonStringEnumConverter(new DictionaryLookupNamingPolicy(dictionary, namingPolicy), allowIntegerValues).CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options);
        else
            return baseConverter.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options);
    }
}

public class JsonNamingPolicyDecorator : JsonNamingPolicy 
{
    readonly JsonNamingPolicy? underlyingNamingPolicy;
    
    public JsonNamingPolicyDecorator(JsonNamingPolicy? underlyingNamingPolicy) => this.underlyingNamingPolicy = underlyingNamingPolicy;
    public override string ConvertName (string name) => underlyingNamingPolicy?.ConvertName(name) ?? name;
}

internal class DictionaryLookupNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicyDecorator 
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;

    public DictionaryLookupNamingPolicy(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, JsonNamingPolicy? underlyingNamingPolicy) : base(underlyingNamingPolicy) => this.dictionary = dictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    public override string ConvertName (string name) => dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out var value) ? value : base.ConvertName(name);
}
```

Then decorate your `enum`:

```
public enum Example 
{
    Trick,
    Treat,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Trick-Or-Treat")]
    TrickOrTreat,
}
```

And use the converter standalone as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter() },
    // Set other options as required:
    WriteIndented = true,
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(values, options);
```

To register the converter with ASP.NET Core, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57334833/3744182) to *[JsonConverter equivalent in using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56360401/3744182)* by [Mani Gandham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173322/mani-gandham).

Notes:

- In .NET 6 and earlier, `JsonStringEnumConverter` ignores its naming policy during deserialization, see *[System.Text.Json: JsonStringEnumConverter ignores its JsonNamingPolicy during deserialization #31619](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31619)* for details. This was fixed with [pull 73348](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/73348).
- In .Net Core 3.x the converter may not work as desired with `[Flags]` enums such as:

  ```
  [Flags]
  public enum Example 
  {
      Trick = (1<<0),
      Treat = (1<<1),
      [EnumMember(Value = "Trick-Or-Treat")]
      TrickOrTreat = (1<<2),
  }
  ```

  Simple values like `Example.TrickOrTreat` are renamed properly, but composite values like `Example.Trick | Example.TrickOrTreat` are not.  The result for the latter should be `"Trick, Trick-Or-Treat"` but is instead is `"Trick, TrickOrTreat"`.

  In .NET 5 this is fixed, see [Issue #31622](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31622) for details.

Demo .NET 7 fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tE1GKx).

**If you need to *round-trip* an enum with custom value names in .NET 6 or earlier** you will need to create a generic converter + converter factory from scratch.  This is somewhat involved in general as it is necessary to handle parsing of integer and string values, renaming of each component of a `[Flags]` enum value, and converting enums of all possible [underlying types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#enum-declarations) (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `ulong` etc).

[`JsonStringEnumMemberConverter`](https://github.com/Macross-Software/core/blob/5a370afc9f7432ea9e504a825ef5a3923d9a6800/ClassLibraries/Macross.Json.Extensions/Code/System.Text.Json.Serialization/JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.cs) from the aforementioned [`Macross.Json.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions) appears to provide this functionality when the enum is decorated with [`[EnumMember(Value = "custom name")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute) attributes; install the package `Macross.Json.Extensions` and then do:

```
// This third-party converter was placed in a system namespace.
[JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum Example 
{
    Trick,
    Treat,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Trick-Or-Treat")]
    TrickOrTreat,
}
```

See the docs [here](https://github.com/Macross-Software/core/tree/develop/ClassLibraries/Macross.Json.Extensions#enumerations) for usage details.

Alternatively you could roll your own.  One possibility is shown below.  It is written against .NET 6 and would need some backporting to earlier versions:

```
public class JsonPropertyNameStringEnumConverter : GeneralJsonStringEnumConverter
{
    public JsonPropertyNameStringEnumConverter() : base() { }
    public JsonPropertyNameStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = default, bool allowIntegerValues = true) : base(namingPolicy, allowIntegerValues) { }

    protected override bool TryOverrideName(Type enumType, string name, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> overrideName)
    {
        if (JsonEnumExtensions.TryGetEnumAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>(enumType, name, out var attr) && attr.Name != null)
        {
            overrideName = attr.Name.AsMemory();
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryOverrideName(enumType, name, out overrideName);
    }
}

public class JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter : GeneralJsonStringEnumConverter
{
    public JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter() : base() { }
    public JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = default, bool allowIntegerValues = true) : base(namingPolicy, allowIntegerValues) { }

    protected override bool TryOverrideName(Type enumType, string name, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> overrideName)
    {
        if (JsonEnumExtensions.TryGetEnumAttribute<System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute>(enumType, name, out var attr) && attr.Value != null)
        {
            overrideName = attr.Value.AsMemory();
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryOverrideName(enumType, name, out overrideName);
    }
}

public delegate bool TryOverrideName(Type enumType, string name, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> overrideName);

public class GeneralJsonStringEnumConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    readonly JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy;
    readonly bool allowIntegerValues;
    
    public GeneralJsonStringEnumConverter() : this(null, true) { }
    
    public GeneralJsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = default, bool allowIntegerValues = true) => (this.namingPolicy, this.allowIntegerValues) = (namingPolicy, allowIntegerValues);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsEnum || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert)?.IsEnum == true;

    public sealed override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) ?? typeToConvert;
        var flagged = enumType.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), true);
        JsonConverter enumConverter;
        TryOverrideName tryOverrideName = (Type t, string n, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> o) => TryOverrideName(t, n, out o);
        var converterType = (flagged ? typeof(FlaggedJsonEnumConverter<>) : typeof(UnflaggedJsonEnumConverter<>)).MakeGenericType(new [] {enumType});
        enumConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType,
                                                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                                binder: null,
                                                                args: new object[] { namingPolicy!, allowIntegerValues, tryOverrideName },
                                                                culture: null)!;
        if (enumType == typeToConvert)
            return enumConverter;
        else
        {
            var nullableConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NullableConverterDecorator<>).MakeGenericType(new [] {enumType}), 
                                                                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                                            binder: null,
                                                                            args: new object[] { enumConverter },
                                                                            culture: null)!;
            return nullableConverter;
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual bool TryOverrideName(Type enumType, string name, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> overrideName)
    {
        overrideName = default;
        return false;
    }
    
    class FlaggedJsonEnumConverter<TEnum> : JsonEnumConverterBase<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, Enum
    {
        private const char FlagSeparatorChar = ',';
        private const string FlagSeparatorString = ", ";

        public FlaggedJsonEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy, bool allowNumbers, TryOverrideName? tryOverrideName) : base(namingPolicy, allowNumbers, tryOverrideName) { }

        protected override bool TryFormatAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, TEnum value, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> name)
        {
            UInt64 UInt64Value = JsonEnumExtensions.ToUInt64(value, EnumTypeCode);
            var index = enumData.BinarySearchFirst(UInt64Value, EntryComparer);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                // A single flag
                name = enumData[index].name;
                return true;
            }
            if (UInt64Value != 0)
            {
                StringBuilder? sb = null;
                for (int i = (~index) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if ((UInt64Value & enumData[i].UInt64Value) ==  enumData[i].UInt64Value && enumData[i].UInt64Value != 0)
                    {
                        if (sb == null)
                        {
                            sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.Append(enumData[i].name.Span);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.Insert(0, FlagSeparatorString);
                            sb.Insert(0, enumData[i].name.Span);
                        }
                        UInt64Value -= enumData[i].UInt64Value;
                    }
                }
                if (UInt64Value == 0 && sb != null)
                {
                    name = sb.ToString().AsMemory();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            name = default;
            return false;
        }

        protected override bool TryReadAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> nameLookup, ReadOnlyMemory<char> name, out TEnum value)
        {
            UInt64 UInt64Value = 0;
            foreach (var slice in name.Split(FlagSeparatorChar, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries))
            {
                if (JsonEnumExtensions.TryLookupBest<TEnum>(enumData, nameLookup, slice, out TEnum thisValue))
                    UInt64Value |= thisValue.ToUInt64(EnumTypeCode);
                else
                {
                    value = default;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            value = JsonEnumExtensions.FromUInt64<TEnum>(UInt64Value);
            return true;
        }
    }

    class UnflaggedJsonEnumConverter<TEnum> : JsonEnumConverterBase<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, Enum
    {
        public UnflaggedJsonEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy, bool allowNumbers, TryOverrideName? tryOverrideName) : base(namingPolicy, allowNumbers, tryOverrideName) { }

        protected override bool TryFormatAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, TEnum value, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> name)
        {
            var index = enumData.BinarySearchFirst(JsonEnumExtensions.ToUInt64(value, EnumTypeCode), EntryComparer);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                name = enumData[index].name;
                return true;
            }
            name = default;
            return false;
        }
        protected override bool TryReadAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> nameLookup, ReadOnlyMemory<char> name, out TEnum value) => 
            JsonEnumExtensions.TryLookupBest(enumData, nameLookup, name, out value);
    }

    abstract class JsonEnumConverterBase<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, Enum
    {
        protected static TypeCode EnumTypeCode { get; } = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum));  
        protected static Func<EnumData<TEnum>, UInt64, int> EntryComparer { get; } = (item, key) => item.UInt64Value.CompareTo(key);

        private bool AllowNumbers { get; }
        private EnumData<TEnum> [] EnumData { get; }
        private ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> NameLookup { get; }

        public JsonEnumConverterBase(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy, bool allowNumbers, TryOverrideName? tryOverrideName) 
        {
            this.AllowNumbers = allowNumbers;
            this.EnumData = JsonEnumExtensions.GetData<TEnum>(namingPolicy, tryOverrideName).ToArray();
            this.NameLookup = JsonEnumExtensions.GetLookupTable<TEnum>(this.EnumData);
        }

        public sealed override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Todo: consider caching a small number of JsonEncodedText values for the first N enums encountered, as is done in 
            // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs
            if (TryFormatAsString(EnumData, value, out var name))
                writer.WriteStringValue(name.Span);
            else
            {
                if (!AllowNumbers)
                    throw new JsonException();
                WriteEnumAsNumber(writer, value);
            }
        }

        protected abstract bool TryFormatAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, TEnum value, out ReadOnlyMemory<char> name);

        protected abstract bool TryReadAsString(EnumData<TEnum> [] enumData, ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> nameLookup, ReadOnlyMemory<char> name, out TEnum value);

        public sealed override TEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            reader.TokenType switch
            {
                JsonTokenType.String => TryReadAsString(EnumData, NameLookup, reader.GetString().AsMemory(), out var value) ? value : throw new JsonException(),
                JsonTokenType.Number => AllowNumbers ? ReadNumberAsEnum(ref reader) : throw new JsonException(),
                _ => throw new JsonException(),
            };

        static void WriteEnumAsNumber(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value)
        {
            switch (EnumTypeCode)
            {
                case TypeCode.SByte:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, SByte>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int16>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int32>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int64>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Byte:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, Byte>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt16>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt32>(ref value));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt64>(ref value));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new JsonException();
            }
        }

        static TEnum ReadNumberAsEnum(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
        {
            switch (EnumTypeCode)
            {
                case TypeCode.SByte:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetSByte();
                        return Unsafe.As<SByte, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetInt16();
                        return Unsafe.As<Int16, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetInt32();
                        return Unsafe.As<Int32, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetInt64();
                        return Unsafe.As<Int64, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.Byte:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetByte();
                        return Unsafe.As<Byte, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetUInt16();
                        return Unsafe.As<UInt16, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetUInt32();
                        return Unsafe.As<UInt32, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    {
                        var i = reader.GetUInt64();
                        return Unsafe.As<UInt64, TEnum>(ref i);
                    };
                default:
                    throw new JsonException();
            }
        }
    }
}

public sealed class NullableConverterDecorator<T> : JsonConverter<T?> where T : struct
{
    // Read() and Write() are never called with null unless HandleNull is overwridden -- which it is not.
    readonly JsonConverter<T> innerConverter;
    public NullableConverterDecorator(JsonConverter<T> innerConverter) => this.innerConverter = innerConverter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerConverter));
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => innerConverter.Read(ref reader, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert)!, options);
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => innerConverter.Write(writer, value!.Value, options);
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => base.CanConvert(type) && innerConverter.CanConvert(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)!);
}

internal readonly record struct EnumData<TEnum>(ReadOnlyMemory<char> name, TEnum value, UInt64 UInt64Value) where TEnum : struct, Enum;

internal static class JsonEnumExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetEnumAttribute<TAttribute>(Type type, string name, [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out TAttribute? attribute) where TAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        var member = type.GetMember(name).SingleOrDefault();
        attribute = member?.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(false);
        return attribute != null;
    }
    
    public static UInt64 ToUInt64<TEnum>(this TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, Enum => value.ToUInt64(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));
    
    internal static UInt64 ToUInt64<TEnum>(this TEnum value, TypeCode enumTypeCode) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        Debug.Assert(enumTypeCode == Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));
        return enumTypeCode switch
        {
            TypeCode.SByte => unchecked((ulong)Unsafe.As<TEnum, SByte>(ref value)),
            TypeCode.Int16 => unchecked((ulong)Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int16>(ref value)),
            TypeCode.Int32 => unchecked((ulong)Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int32>(ref value)),
            TypeCode.Int64 => unchecked((ulong)Unsafe.As<TEnum, Int64>(ref value)),
            TypeCode.Byte => Unsafe.As<TEnum, Byte>(ref value),
            TypeCode.UInt16 => Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt16>(ref value),
            TypeCode.UInt32 => Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt32>(ref value),
            TypeCode.UInt64 => Unsafe.As<TEnum, UInt64>(ref value),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException(enumTypeCode.ToString()),
        };
    }

    public static TEnum FromUInt64<TEnum>(this UInt64 value) where TEnum : struct, Enum => value.FromUInt64<TEnum>(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));
    
    internal static TEnum FromUInt64<TEnum>(this UInt64 value, TypeCode enumTypeCode) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        Debug.Assert(enumTypeCode == Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));
        switch (enumTypeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((SByte)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<SByte, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((Int16)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<Int16, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((Int32)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<Int32, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((Int64)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<Int64, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((Byte)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<Byte, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((UInt16)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<UInt16, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((UInt32)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<UInt32, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                {
                    var i = unchecked((UInt64)value);
                    return Unsafe.As<UInt64, TEnum>(ref i);
                };
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(enumTypeCode.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    // Return data about the enum sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude)
    internal static IEnumerable<EnumData<TEnum>> GetData<TEnum>(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy, TryOverrideName? tryOverrideName) where TEnum : struct, Enum => 
        GetData<TEnum>(namingPolicy, tryOverrideName, Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));

    // Return data about the enum sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude)
    internal static IEnumerable<EnumData<TEnum>> GetData<TEnum>(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy, TryOverrideName? tryOverrideName, TypeCode enumTypeCode) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        Debug.Assert(enumTypeCode == Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TEnum)));
        var names = Enum.GetNames<TEnum>();
        var values = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>();
        return names.Zip(values, (n, v) => 
            { 
                if (tryOverrideName == null || !tryOverrideName(typeof(TEnum), n, out var jsonName))
                    jsonName = (namingPolicy == null ? n.AsMemory() : namingPolicy.ConvertName(n).AsMemory());
                return new EnumData<TEnum>(jsonName, v, v.ToUInt64(enumTypeCode));
            });
    }
    
    internal static ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> GetLookupTable<TEnum>(EnumData<TEnum> [] namesAndValues) where TEnum : struct, Enum => 
        Enumerable.Range(0, namesAndValues.Length).ToLookup(i => namesAndValues[i].name, CharMemoryComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    
    internal static bool TryLookupBest<TEnum>(EnumData<TEnum> [] namesAndValues, ILookup<ReadOnlyMemory<char>, int> lookupTable, ReadOnlyMemory<char> name, out TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        int i = 0;
        int firstMatch = -1;
        foreach (var index in lookupTable[name])
        {
            if (firstMatch == -1)
                firstMatch = index;
            else 
            {
                if (i == 1 && MemoryExtensions.Equals(namesAndValues[firstMatch].name.Span, name.Span, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    value = namesAndValues[firstMatch].value;
                    return true;
                }
                if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(namesAndValues[index].name.Span, name.Span, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    value = namesAndValues[index].value;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        value = (firstMatch == -1 ? default : namesAndValues[firstMatch].value);
        return firstMatch != -1;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> Split(this ReadOnlyMemory<char> chars, char separator, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
    {
        int index;
        while ((index = chars.Span.IndexOf(separator)) >= 0)
        {
            var slice = chars.Slice(0, index);
            if ((options & StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) == StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
                slice = slice.Trim();
            if ((options & StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) == 0 || slice.Length > 0)
                yield return slice;
            chars = chars.Slice(index + 1);
        }
        if ((options & StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) == StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
            chars = chars.Trim();
        if ((options & StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) == 0 || chars.Length > 0)
            yield return chars;
    }
}

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<TValue, TKey>(this TValue [] list, TKey key, Func<TValue, TKey, int> comparer)
    {
        if (list == null || comparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        int low = 0;
        int high = list.Length - 1;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            var mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
            var order = comparer(list[mid], key);
            if (order == 0)
                return mid;
            else if (order > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        return ~low;
    }
    
    public static int BinarySearchFirst<TValue, TKey>(this TValue [] list, TKey key, Func<TValue, TKey, int> comparer)
    {
        int index = list.BinarySearch(key, comparer);
        for (; index > 0 && comparer(list[index-1], key) == 0; index--)
            ;
        return index;
    }
}

public class CharMemoryComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>
{
    public static CharMemoryComparer OrdinalIgnoreCase { get; } = new CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    public static CharMemoryComparer Ordinal { get; }  = new CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison.Ordinal);

    readonly StringComparison comparison;
    CharMemoryComparer(StringComparison comparison) => this.comparison = comparison;
    public bool Equals(ReadOnlyMemory<char> x, ReadOnlyMemory<char> y) => MemoryExtensions.Equals(x.Span, y.Span, comparison);
    public int GetHashCode(ReadOnlyMemory<char> obj) => String.GetHashCode(obj.Span, comparison);
}
```

If your `enum` is annotated with `EnumMember` attributes, use `JsonEnumMemberStringEnumConverter`.  If annotated with `JsonPropertyName` attributes as in the question, use `JsonPropertyNameStringEnumConverter`.

Notes:

- Round-tripping of enums when naming policies are in use is fully supported (unlike Microsoft's `JsonStringEnumConverter` which does not fully support naming policies when reading).
- Handling of enum members with identical values is consistent with `JsonStringEnumConverter`.
- Nullables are supported automatically, but dictionary keys are not.

Demo .NET 6 fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MM4a4l).

Comment: Seems that this will be a feature in v.5. In the meatime, this lib works: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/

Comment: Maybe this library can also help you:
https://github.com/StefH/System.Text.Json.EnumExtensions

Comment: Only works for Serialization :(
Cant deserialize similar way

Comment: This was a great answer for how to achieve goals using .NET Core 3.1, I'll accept a new answer that provides a succinct example for .NET 5, including serialization and deserialization

Comment: @CraigSmitham - unfortunately [Support for EnumMemberAttribute in JsonConverterEnum #31081](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081) is still open in .Net 5.0.  As far as I know the only enum-related thing that got fixed is [System.Text.Json: Naming policies are not applied consistently to `[Flags]` enum values by JsonStringEnumConverter. #31622](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31622).  A roundup of all .Net 5 `System.Text.Json` improvements can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41313)

Comment: @dbc :-(. Thanks for the additional context

Comment: @CraigSmitham - answer updated with a converter that round-trips in .NET 6.

Comment: God bless you for this answer. That Nuget package did the trick after way too much time spent looking through GitHub feature requests

Answer (score 2):

For .NET5.0 or greater ,you can add a JsonConverter

```
public class EnumDescriptionJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ValueType>
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert.IsEnum || typeToConvert.IsGenericType && typeToConvert.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1 && typeToConvert.GenericTypeArguments[0].IsEnum;
    }
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override ValueType Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ValueType value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        else
            writer.WriteStringValue(GetDescription((value as Enum)!));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get description
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static string GetDescription(Enum source)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = source.GetType().GetField(source.ToString());
        if (fi == null) return source.ToString();
        System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0) return attributes[0].Description;
        else return source.ToString();
    }
}
```

The model for serialization

```cs
        public class MyClass
        {
            public MyEnum MyEnumWith0 { get; set; }
            public MyEnum MyEnumWith1 { get; set; }
            public MyEnum? NullableMyEnumWith0 { get; set; }
            public MyEnum? NullableMyEnumWith1 { get; set; }
            public MyEnum? NullableMyEnumWithNull { get; set; }
            public MyEnum? NullableMyEnumWith2 { get; set; }
        }

        public enum MyEnum
        {
            [Description("Description")]
            Key = 1,
            NoDescriptionKey = 2,
        }
```

Used and Test

```cs
    JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
    Assert.Equal(@"{
      ""MyEnumWith0"": 0,
      ""MyEnumWith1"": 1,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith0"": 0,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith1"": 1,
      ""NullableMyEnumWithNull"": null,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith2"": 2
    }", JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, jsonSerializerOptions));
        jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
        jsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        Assert.Equal(@"{
      ""MyEnumWith0"": 0,
      ""MyEnumWith1"": ""Key"",
      ""NullableMyEnumWith0"": 0,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith1"": ""Key"",
      ""NullableMyEnumWithNull"": null,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith2"": ""NoDescriptionKey""
    }", JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, jsonSerializerOptions));
        jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
        jsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EnumDescriptionJsonConverter());
        Assert.Equal(@"{
      ""MyEnumWith0"": ""0"",
      ""MyEnumWith1"": ""Description"",
      ""NullableMyEnumWith0"": ""0"",
      ""NullableMyEnumWith1"": ""Description"",
      ""NullableMyEnumWithNull"": null,
      ""NullableMyEnumWith2"": ""NoDescriptionKey""
    }", JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, jsonSerializerOptions));
```

This converter is only available for serialization

Comment: This does not work. Renders the same result as JsonStringEnumConverter

Comment: @JaimeBula I add null check and test into answer,this solution just for .net5.0 or greater

Comment: The code here is largely okay, but I don't think you should be using `[Description]` as the string value is _not_ a human-readable description of the value.