# JsonConverter will not convert enum with dashes(hyphens)

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm trying to convert a JSON object to a C# class using .NET Core (5) System.Text.Json JsonSerializer.Deserialize() but it's throwing a JsonException.  I believe the reason is because the string values it's trying to convert to an enum contains dashes (hyphens).  The enum looks like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum TypeEnum
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "loopback")]
        Loopback = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value = "link-local")]
        LinkLocal = 2,
    }
```

The JSON object is quite large but the part that is causing the exception is this:

```
{
    "address": "fe80::3617:ebff:fec0:b54c/64"
    "family": "inet6",
    "type": "link-local"
}
```

When the JsonSerializer encounters "type":"link-local", it doesn't like "link-local" and throws. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Was asked for the exception so here it is:

```
 System.Text.Json.JsonException : The JSON value could not be converted to DmIfInfoAddr+TypeEnum. Path: $[0].addrs[0].type | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 144.
  Stack Trace: 
    ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException(String message)
    EnumConverter`1.ReadWithQuotes(Utf8JsonReader& reader)
    EnumConverter`1.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
    ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
    JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
    ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
    JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
    JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
    JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: After a cursory review of the `EnumConverter` in the runtime repo, it doesn't appear that it respects the `EnumMemberAttribute` (which isn't technically part of System.Text.Json).  I would recommend writing a custom coverter.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: Related or duplicate: [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059989/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now there is no support by `System.Text.Json` for `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes as you can see in the migration from `Newtonsoft.Json` [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson). There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081) which you can track. As workaround you can try to use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` from [`Macross.Json.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/).