# Deserialise Enum From JSON String with Spaces

Tags: c#, json, enums, deserialization, system.text.json

I'll preface this with the fact that I'm trying to avoid using `Newtonsoft.Json` since, ostensibly, `System.Text.Json` is ready for prime-time in .NET 6.

So I have two enums coming from an API and I want to deserialise them using this test method:

```cs
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
public void CanDeserialiseEnumsWithCustomJsonStrings(Enum expected, string jsonName)
{
    jsonName.ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty();
    ReadOnlySpan<char> json = $"{{\"TestEnum\":\"{jsonName}\"}}";

    Type constructed = typeof(TestEnumWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(expected.GetType());
        
    var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, constructed);

    constructed.GetProperty("TestEnum").GetValue(res).ShouldBe(expected);
}

private class TestEnumWrapper<T> where T: struct
{
    public T TestEnum { get; set; }
}
```

(Yes I know that this could be done with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>()`, I want to be able to test many types with this test so I need the reflection AFAICT).

The first one, works fine:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum RecordType
{
        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        Country = 1,

        [JsonPropertyName("destinationOrbit")]
        DestinationOrbit = 2,

        [JsonPropertyName("engine")]
        Engine = 3,
        //etc...

}
```

The second one, fails on the deserialization, this seems to be due to the spaces in the names.

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum ObjectClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Rocket Body")]
    RocketBody,
    [JsonPropertyName("Rocket Debris")]
    RocketDebris,
    [JsonPropertyName("Rocket Fragmentation Debris")]
    RocketFragmentationDebris,
    [JsonPropertyName("Rocket Mission Related Object")]
    RocketMissionRelatedObject,
    //etc...
}
```

The API is controlled by the European Space Agency, so somehow, I don't think I'll be able to persuade them to rationalise the response a bit more.

Is there any way around this?

---

Some have asked for an example of the JSON I'm trying to deserialise. I'm currently working on the Attributes part of this blob:

```
{
            "type": "object",
            "attributes": {
                "shape": null,
                "xSectMin": null,
                "satno": null,
                "depth": null,
                "objectClass": "Rocket Fragmentation Debris",
                "cosparId": null,
                "length": null,
                "height": null,
                "mass": null,
                "xSectMax": null,
                "vimpelId": 84303,
                "xSectAvg": null,
                "name": null
            },
            "relationships": {
                "states": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/states",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/states"
                    }
                },
                "initialOrbits": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/initial-orbits",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/initial-orbits"
                    }
                },
                "destinationOrbits": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/destination-orbits",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/destination-orbits"
                    }
                },
                "operators": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/operators",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/operators"
                    }
                },
                "launch": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/launch",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/launch"
                    }
                },
                "reentry": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/objects/61345/relationships/reentry",
                        "related": "/api/objects/61345/reentry"
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": "61345",
            "links": {
                "self": "/api/objects/61345"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not supported by System.Text.Json.  See: [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059989/3744182), which has some suggested workarounds.

Comment: Deserializing `RecordType` works because, as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-6.0#remarks), ***Reading is case insensitive.** Writing can be customized by using a `JsonNamingPolicy`.*  Note that it's implied that reading cannot be customized by a `JsonNamingPolicy`.

Comment: Works fine in `Newtonsoft.Json`. Don't torture yourself. 
It's possible in `System.Text.Json` but requires lots of custom code or a Nuget.

Comment: Can you post the real json that you have pls?  It is hard understand what is the problem, why you have to deserialize or serialize enums?

Comment: @Serge - Added :)

Comment: @Charles - I'm all good with with a nuget if you know one that works well?

Comment: @dbc - I honestly thought this would've been fixed for dotnet 6... That's a shame

Comment: Oh and to answer the second part of your question @Serge, I don't really like leaving things as strings when there's actually a finite number of them... Seems like a textbook case of should-probably-be-an-enum imho

Comment: @Persistence It is ok, I am mostly wondering why you are not allowed to Newtonsoft.Json?  System.Text.Json is very tricky and bugy. A half of its featrures is still not working properly.

Comment: @Serge - There's nothing stopping me using it, it's more that I don't want to if I can help it. With dotnet 6, supposedly Text.Json was ready for prime time, so I was trying to avoid writing newtonsoft dependent stuff if I could help it. If there's no straightforward solution then I'll bin it off

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution for `System.Text.Json`

I used the Nuget package `System.Text.Json.EnumExtensions`
https://github.com/StefH/System.Text.Json.EnumExtensions

```
// you probably want these options somewhere global
private JsonSerializerOptions options;

private class TestEnumWrapper<T> where T : struct
{
    public T TestEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum ObjectClass
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Body")]
    RocketBody,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Debris")]
    RocketDebris,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Fragmentation Debris")]
    RocketFragmentationDebris,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Mission Related Object")]
    RocketMissionRelatedObject,
    //etc...
}

private void CanDeserialiseEnumsWithCustomJsonStrings(Enum expected, string jsonName)
{
    var json = $"{{\"TestEnum\":\"{jsonName}\"}}";

    Type constructed = typeof(TestEnumWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(expected.GetType());

    var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, constructed, options);
}


public void Test()
{
    this.options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport());

    var testSerialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new TestEnumWrapper<ObjectClass>() 
        { TestEnum = ObjectClass.RocketBody }, options);

    // Test Deserialize
    CanDeserialiseEnumsWithCustomJsonStrings(ObjectClass.RocketBody, "Rocket Body");
}
```

You only have to add the `new JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport()` to the `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` for this to work.

If you want to use the Converter as an Attribute you have to add an parameterless constructor to the class `JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport`

```
public JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport() : this(namingPolicy : null, allowIntegerValues : true,
    parseEnumMemberAttribute : true, parseDisplayAttribute : false, parseDescriptionAttribute : false)
{

}
```

Comment: Going to leave it another hour or so to see if someone knows of a decent System.Text.Json option, if they don't, then I'll accept this one :) Although it would be good if you could add a short summary of what you've done because code-only answers aren't rated in these parts (even though I can see what you've done). Cheers bud

Comment: @Persistence i added a version for `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Thanking you my good sir, you are a scholar and a gent. Does it need the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport))]` attribute?

Comment: @Persistence it works out of the box with the options like in my example, if you want to use the converter as an Attribute you have to add a parameterless constructor inside the Library class. (I just copied the 5 files from the nuget into my project, so i can edit them)

Comment: So I've just tested with this code here and I'm actually getting similar results to before I added the nuget, have I missed something? Thank you for being so helpful here

https://gist.github.com/hughesjs/2a34b68588fd2fae3935abdda2dea2e4

Comment: @Persistence uhm it works in my example, if you want me to debug your code, give me a few min. I don't have all your libraries installed.

Comment: Please don't feel obliged, I was mainly asking in case it was obvious. If you're happy to help though, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240494/discussion-between-persistence-and-charles).

Comment: Added  a PR to upstream for your change https://github.com/StefH/System.Text.Json.EnumExtensions/pull/7

Answer (score 2):

try this, I uses Newtonsoft.Json and for test I deserialized only attributes since only they contain enum. You don't need any custom code.

```
var attributes= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

classes

```
    public enum ObjectClass
    {
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Body")]
    RocketBody,
    [EnumMember(Value ="Rocket Debris")]
    RocketDebris,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Rocket Fragmentation Debris")]
    RocketFragmentationDebris,
    [EnumMember(Value ="Rocket Mission Related Object")]
    RocketMissionRelatedObject
    }

    public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("attributes")]
        public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Attributes
    {
        [JsonProperty("shape")]
        public object Shape { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xSectMin")]
        public object XSectMin { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("satno")]
        public object Satno { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("depth")]
        public object Depth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("objectClass")]
        public ObjectClass ObjectClass { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cosparId")]
        public object CosparId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("length")]
        public object Length { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public object Height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mass")]
        public object Mass { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xSectMax")]
        public object XSectMax { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vimpelId")]
        public long VimpelId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xSectAvg")]
        public object XSectAvg { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

test

```
json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributes); 
attributes= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

result

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "shape": null,
    "xSectMin": null,
    "satno": null,
    "depth": null,
    "objectClass": 2,
    "cosparId": null,
    "length": null,
    "height": null,
    "mass": null,
    "xSectMax": null,
    "vimpelId": 84303,
    "xSectAvg": null,
    "name": null
  }
}
```