# Json conversion of enums to strings

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class JsonError
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum Number
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "0")]
        Pass,
        [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
        Miscalc,
        [EnumMember(Value = "2")]
        ReadError
    }

    public Number ErrorNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I try to deserialize this JSON file...

```
{
  "CriticalErrors": [
    {
      "ErrorNumber": "1"
    },
    {
      "ErrorNumber": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

... into this class:

```
public class TestBehavior
{
    public List<JsonError> CriticalErrors { get; set; } = new List<JsonError>();
}
```

But I get this error: **"The JSON value could not be converted to MyNamespace.JsonError+Number. Path: $.CriticalErrors[0].ErrorNumber | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 24."**

Any ideas what could have gone wrong? The values "1" and "2" obviously exist in the enum, and the format seems correct. Unfortunately, the error message does not tell me what exactly has gone wrong, so I am quite lost here.

Comment: Conversion of a JSON to classes can be done using: [Paste JSON or XML as classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022). It will get you another class than the one you are using now.

Comment: The error message you are seeing is from System.Text.Json, not Json.NET, and System.Text.Json does not support custom names for enums at all.  See [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061296/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Oh my gosh, you are right. For some reason, in my deserialize class, I referenced the wrong package, and since I relied heavily on Intellisense completion, I didn't even notice this. Thanks! (If you like, you can write this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Your problem is that you are actually using System.Text.Json not Json.NET to deserialize your JSON, and System.Text.Json does not support use of [`EnumMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-7.0) to specify custom names for enums.  (Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2U01dr)).

To use `EnumMemberAttribute` you must either:

1. Switch to Json.NET, or
2. Use one of the answers from [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059989/3744182).

**How to determine the serializer used?**. There are two JSON serializers widely used in .NET Core: [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to) and [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).  If an exception is thrown while deserializing JSON, and

- The exception type comes from the namespace `System.Text.Json` (e.g. [`System.Text.Json.JsonException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception?view=net-7.0)), OR
- The error message contains information about the `LineNumber` and `BytePositionInLine`, e.g. `LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 24.`

Then the error was generated by System.Text.Json.

If an exception is thrown and

- The exception type comes from the namespace `Newtonsoft.Json` (e.g. [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonserializationexception.htm), OR
- The exception message includes information about the `line` and `position`, e.g. `line 4, position 28.`

Then the error was generate by Json.NET.

`BytePositionInLine` will only ever be reported by System.Text.Json because it deserializes directly from UTF8 `byte` streams and thus has information about byte positioning.  Conversely Json.NET deserializes from UTF16 `char` streams, and so does not have information about byte positioning, just character positioning.